# Wordpress - user taken to a specific protected page on login

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I generally setup sites in Wordpress, and not a complete beginner to it.  I definitely don't have advanced programming skills though either.  Here is what I have been asked to setup:

I need to set up a site so that people can login, and view technical drawings associated to them. Each client would have their own protected page that contains just their drawings.   Ideally, they'd be taken right to that page when they login.  And, they would be able to access the general public parts of the site, but not the other protected 'user pages' that contain other clients drawings.

Is this something that can be achieved with any existing plug-ins?  Is Wordpress even suited for this kind of site (again, it's what I am used to using which is why I am looking for a solution tailored to it).

Thanks for any input.  I hope my wording is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, but [this Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/privatecontent-multilevel-content-plugin/1467885?ref=LCweb) looks like it will do what you need.

> **PrivateContent** it’s a simple and fast solution to power up your wordpress website by adding a multilevel login, private areas, user private pages and users management features. It’s easy to use and doesn’t require any scripting knowledge!

Comment: Indeed it does.  Thanks very much!  I'll have to give it a try.